# C - Recursion with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I am trying to write a recursion function that takes an array as an argument and returns the MIN and MAX values. So far i can only get `MAX`. I tried to add a pointer to send back the minimum value but for some reason, it always crashes and shows lots of *warnings*.

Please help me figure out what is wrong in my code.

```
int MinMaxArray(int arr[], int size, int* min)
{
    if (size == 1)
        return arr[0];

    if (arr[size - 1] > MinMaxArray(arr, (size - 1), &min))
        return arr[size - 1];
    else
        return MinMaxArray(arr, (size - 1), &min);
}
```

so i tried this but the min that return is allways the one in index 0 
how to make it works?

```
int MinMaxArray(int arr[], int size, int* min)
{
    if (size == 1)
    {
        *min = arr[0];
        return arr[0];
    }

    if (arr[size - 1] < MinMaxArray(arr, (size - 1), min))
        *min = arr[size - 1];
    else
        *min = MinMaxArray(arr, (size - 1), min);

    if (arr[size - 1] > MinMaxArray(arr, (size - 1), min))
        return arr[size - 1];
    else
        return MinMaxArray(arr, (size - 1), min);
}
```

Comment: `&min` --> `min`.

Comment: Why do you have that third argument? You never use it.

Comment: ...Oh, and change `>` to `<`.

Comment: If this is your attempt of getting a grasp around recursion ... well, you're nearly there. But if this is for some real problem, eliminate recursion for good.

Comment: i dont understand you guys

Comment: and yes im learning how to do recursion and im new in that

Comment: i dont know how to combine the pointer in my code to return min value to without ruin the max returning

Comment: "it always crashes and shows lots of warnings" - So why do you ignore the warnings? No wonder it crashes! Provide a [mcve].

Comment: well now there are no warnings thanks to you guys! but still cant figue how to return the min it keep return to valuse in index 0....

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC BY-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int MinMaxArray(int arr[], int size, int *min){
    assert(arr != NULL && size > 0);

    if (size == 1){
        *min = arr[0];
        return arr[0];
    }
    int max = MinMaxArray(arr, size - 1, min);

    if (arr[size - 1] < *min)
        *min = arr[size - 1];

    return  (arr[size - 1] > max) ? arr[size - 1] : max;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 1,5,9,2,6,-4,8,3,7 };
    int min, max = MinMaxArray(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), &min);

    printf("max:%d, min:%d\n", max, min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is "assert" can i do it without it?

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga _can i do it without it?_ yes delete this or Make comment `//assert(arr != NULL && size > 0);`

Comment: `assert` is an assertion that the condition is satisfied by this function. If the condition is not satisfied, an error message is displayed and aborted.

Comment: another question there is any way of doin it without static veriables in the function?

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga `max` can be replaced with a function call. However, it will wastefully execute the function multiple times.

Comment: i tried it but same problem as my code the max works and min not its just return the value on index 0

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga Note that applying the function to the rest determines the remaining `min` and `max`.

Comment: yep i notice that, thats why with a static veriable max it works and without not, but still there is any way of remove the static veriable?

Comment: grrrr i tried so hard to make it work with no static veriables but its just not working please help

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga Ahh _the value on index 0_ That is because it is unconditionally `*min = arr[0];`. For example, do [this](http://ideone.com/R22LvI). However, the usability of the function is bad with this. ( ; _ ;)

Comment: Moreover, it consumes more resources than a single variable.

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga I will not print the address. You mistyped something.

Comment: this is the full code a littlebit diffrent but same goal and i cant find the problem -->: [link](http://ideone.com/lYtwRQ)

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga `int i, size, *arr;
 int max = 0, min = *arr ;` : `arr` is uninitialized variable. You was using it.

Comment: (`int max = 0, min = *arr` --> `int max = 0, min` then) Put `min = *arr;` before `max = MinMaxArray(arr, size, &min);`

Comment: i changed the `min= *arr`  to  `min=&arr`  and it works!!! fianlly and i dont know how...

Comment: `int max = 0, min = *arr` --> `int max = 0, min`

Answer (score 0):

The third argument specified for the call

```
MinMaxArray(arr, (size - 1), &min)
```

has wrong type relative to the parameter declaration.

The argument has type `int **` while the parameter has type `int *`.

Also the minimum element is not calculated.

In C++ there is standard algorithm named `minmax_element` that returns a pair of pointers that point to the maximum an minimum elements of an array.

You could use a similar declaration of the function written in C.

Another approach is to return a pair of indices of the minimum and maximum elements.

To do so you need to declare a structure of two data members.

Below there is shown how the function that returns a pair of indices can be implemented in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct MinMax
{
    size_t min;
    size_t max;
};

struct MinMax minmax_element( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    struct MinMax minmax = { 0, 0 };

    if ( n > 1 )
    {
        struct MinMax current = minmax_element( a + 1, n - 1 );
        ++current.min; ++current.max;

        if ( a[current.min] < a[minmax.min] ) minmax.min = current.min;
        if ( a[minmax.max] < a[current.max] ) minmax.max = current.max;
    }

    return minmax;  
}

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time(NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) a[i]= rand() % ( 2 * N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    struct MinMax minmax = minmax_element( a, N );

    printf( "The minimum is %d\n", a[minmax.min] );
    printf( "The maximum is %d\n", a[minmax.max] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
14 6 7 9 6 7 15 12 0 10 
The minimum is 0
The maximum is 15
```

Take into account that the user can pass to the function an "empty" array that is when the argument that corresponds to the size of the array is equal to 0. In this case your own function implementation has undefined behavior.

If you may not use a structure then the function can be declared like

```
void minmax_element( const int a[], size_t n, size_t *min, size_t *max );
```

Or

```
void minmax_element( const int a[], size_t n, int **min, int **max );
```

It will not be difficult to change the shown above recursive function according to these declarations.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void minmax_element( const int a[], size_t n, size_t *min, size_t *max )
{
    *min = 0;
    *max = 0;

    if ( n > 1 )
    {
        size_t cur_min, cur_max;

        minmax_element( a + 1, n - 1, &cur_min, &cur_max );

        ++cur_min; ++cur_max;

        if ( a[cur_min] < a[*min] ) *min = cur_min;
        if ( a[*max] < a[cur_max] ) *max = cur_max;
    }
}

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time(NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) a[i]= rand() % ( 2 * N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t min;
    size_t max;

    minmax_element( a, N, &min, &max );

    printf( "The minimum is %d\n", a[min] );
    printf( "The maximum is %d\n", a[max] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wtf? i dont knoe C++ i am programing on C.....C!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga I showed you a function implemented in C. Reread one more my post.

Comment: it is to complicated, i appreciate your work. but its not what i asked, sure there are many way to make this MIN&MAX function but i can use only recursion and have to make it as simple as i can

Comment: whats "size_t"?

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga It is an integer type that is used for lengths of arrays.

Comment: cant use it can you please look at my code tell me whats worng?

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga See my updated post where I showed one more function implementation. You may substitute the type size_t for the type int if you want.